# How to use variable from others scripts?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

```
//SCRIPT 1
Class ColorChanger{
    Public string currentColor;
}

//SCRIPT 2
Class Player{
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        If (col.tag != currentColor)
        {
            Debug.Log("GAME OVER");
        }
    }
}
```

If I write SCRIPT 2 part in SCRIPT 1 it will work, but I want to know how to use "currentColor" variable with other scripts?

Comment: I don't have the documention in front of me, But you can look it up, but its called something like GetComponent<T> that you use on the game object to convert it to your type and then you can access public variables

Comment: Thanks johnny found it!!! You too shaman

Answer (score 1):

It all depends if the first script is attached to a GameObject or not.

**1.-** If it is:

```
objectwith1stscript.GetComponent<ColorChanger>().currentColor
```

**2.-** If is not, then you may want the currentColor to be static:

```
public static string currentColor;
```

And then access it via:

```
ColorChanger.currentColor
```

**3.-** if you don't want it to be static for x or y reason (and also no attached to a GameObject), you will need to create an instance of the class, like this:

```
ColorChanger mycolorchanger = new ColorChanger();
```

and then use it like this:

```
mycolorchanger.currentColor
```

If you use 2 or 3 options the first script shouldn't inherit from MonoBehaviour.

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaanks

Comment: you should accept the answer then :)